# how to beautify properly .vue files?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am creating a project with vue framework but I cannot beautify the .vue files.

I have run
`npm install -g vue-beautify`
and
`npm install vue-beautify`

but nothing happens. I have tried both Dreamweaver and atom editors and I get only white letters. Can anyone help on this?

Comment: So you've installed them, but have you tried running them? See the [cli instructions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-beautify#usage)

Comment: It sounds like you are wanting  syntax highlighting in an editor?  If so vue-beautify is definitely not what you are looking for.

Comment: only .vue files are not colored. all other files are colored

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting syntax highlighting in your text editor use this [plugin](https://atom.io/packages/language-vue)
for atom.

I could not find evidence of a syntax highlight package for Dreamweaver.